# How to load large data set in to neo4j (Noe4j-importer)

Tags: csv, batch-file, neo4j, batch-processing

Currently I am working using neo4j in my project.

So I have problem on importing around 20 millions of rows from csv to neo4j database to create nodes and relationships. And I read also the blog written by Micahael Hunger on Neo4j(csv) Batch-Importer.

My question is when I try to run the `import.bat` I get errors:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer
```

But I also add the neo4j to my environment variable path. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Why don't you ask [the developer directly](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/issues)? (Of course after studying the [readme page](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import)).

Answer (score 2):

Just use `neo4j-import` which comes with Neo4j directly these days.

See the docs here:

- http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/
- http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool.html

Answer (score 0):

I just answered to a similar question to another user, with a lot of tips for importing ***millions of nodes in few minutes.***

Hope it helps:
[Import billions of nodes and relationships to Neo4j using Batch Import on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45770769/import-billions-of-nodes-and-relationships-to-neo4j-using-batch-import-on-window/45773618#45773618)