# Use Neo4j Import Tool to add data to existing database

Tags: neo4j

I am using the Neo4j Import Tool to import large datasets to my existing graph. When importing .csv data to my graph i get

```
Directory '...' already contains a database.
```

[Github](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-movies-template/blob/master/README.md) suggests the following solution:

```
"If you see Input error: Directory 'neo4j-community-
3.0.3/data/databases/graph.db' already contains a database, delete the 
graph.db directory and try again."
```

So I have to delete my graph and a new one will be created. I tryed - it works.

But how can I add Data to an existing database, so without deleting mine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Import tool is only for newly created databases.

You can use LOAD CSV cypher command to load into an existing database.
Other tricks are here: https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/

Comment: I loaded a part of my graph using LOAD CSV. But now I have to import 4.2 million relations and LOAD CSV despite of performance optimizations (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45770769/import-billions-of-nodes-and-relationships-to-neo4j-using-batch-import-on-window/45773618#45773618) did not finish even after 4 hours..

Comment: I would say 4 million is still medium-sized dataset, so LOAD CSV should work. If you have the proper data model and the indexes or constraints it should not take that long. 10-20k per second write can be reached. But it depends on so many things, graph model, disk speed, CPU, etc.

Comment: @Boris, can you provide some more details about your application?
Graph model, how you create the relationships, the complete hardware specs used, etc..
4 million is indeed a small-medium size dataset, not a large one.

Comment: It is actually not a complicatde one, I have about 20 lables, about 5000 nodes per label, and about 5 relations per node. Now I need to import 1.4 million events. Each of them is connected to 5 existing nodes. I tryied doing it step by step, so first connect every event to one node in one query then the next and so on. Still loading after few hours

I have 16 GB RAM and i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60 GHz ...should be enough for such datasets.

Comment: my last LOAD CSV command: 
Created 64725 relationships, completed after 3294594 ms, so nearly an hour