# Long time in load_csv

Tags: neo4j, cypher

One of my cypher query to create relations takes very long time. Running for hours and did not complete.

I have loaded the nodes through load_csv which are roughly around 22M.

id is the unique index of all nodes.

Pin label is around 16M.

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Pin(id);
CREATE INDEX ON :Instance(id);

//CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (inst:Instance) ASSERT inst.Id IS UNIQUE;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///home/sranga/work/Neo4j/work/signals.csv' AS line
MATCH (inst1:Pin { id: toInteger(line.Start_port)})
MATCH (inst2:Pin { id: toInteger(line.End_port)})
CREATE (inst1)-[:NET { id: toInteger(line.Signal_id),  Name: line.Name, Signed: toInteger(line.Signed), lbit: toInteger(line.Lbit), rbit: toInteger(line.Rbit)}]->(inst2);
```

Any idea as what is wrong?

Comment: I don't know if this can help you but I answered a similar question some time ago (regarding importing millions of nodes and relationship in an efficient way), so I'll leave the [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45773618/6226370)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use EXPLAIN and PROFILE to get a picture of how the query is run.
Then add it to your question. (ok I saw you copy/pasted, and it does not talk much)

Is your constraint applied or not ? Are the indexes created ?

Try to reduce 10 000 to 1000.
When this number is too high, you get outofmemoryerrors. That should commit every 1000 lines read. 
Follow the progress by connecting a cypher-shell to your instance and run a query to count the NET relationships.
Something like MATCH ()-[net:NET]->() return count(net);   in order to verify that it is increasing (else you stop it, breathe, and send another message )

check the number of lines in your csv with

```
 cat file.csv |wc -l
```

to be able to calculate the end of your import

Comment: Plan: "EXPLAIN"
Statement: "WRITE_ONLY"
Version: "CYPHER 3.3"
Planner: "COST"
Runtime: "INTERPRETED"
Time: 4


Plan: "PROFILE"
Statement: "WRITE_ONLY"
Version: "CYPHER 3.3"
Planner: "COST"
Runtime: "INTERPRETED"
Time: 439
DbHits: 0
Rows: 0

Comment: Not sure as how to attach an image here