# Optimizations for merging graph with million nodes and csv with million rows

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Consider I have graph with following nodes and relationships:

```
(:GPE)-[:contains]->(:PE)-[:has]->(:E)
```

with following attributes:

```
GPE: joinProp1, outProp1, randomProps
PE : joinProp2, outProp2, randomProps
E  : joinProp3, outProp3, randomProps
```

Now consider I have csv of following format:

```
joinCol1, joinCol2, joinCol3, outCol1, outCol2, outCol3, randomProps
```

Now consider I have million rows in this csv file. Also I have million instances of each of `(:GPE),(:PE),(:E)` in graph. I want to merge the graph and csv into new csv. For that I want to map / equate

- joinCol1 with joinProp1
- joinCol2 with joinProp2
- joinCol3 with joinProp3

something like this (pseudo cypher) for each row in csv:

```
MATCH (gpe:GPE {joinProp1:joinCol1})-[:contains]->(pe:PE {joinProp2:joinCol2})-[:has]->(e:E {joinProp3:joinCol3}) RETURN gpe.outProp1, pe.outProp2, e.outProp3
```

So the output csv format would be:

```
joinCol1, joinCol2, joinCol3, outCol1, outCol2, outCol3, outProp1, outProp2, outProp3
```

What is rough minimum execution time estimates (minutes or hours) in which I can complete this task if I create indices on all `joinProp`s and use parameterized cypher (considering I am implementing this simple logic with java api). I just want to know what are rough estimates. We have similar (possibly un-optimized) task implemented and it takes several hours to do this. The challenge is to bring down that execution time. What all things I can do to optimize and bring down execution time to some minutes? Any quick optimization points / links? Will using some approach other than java api provide performance improvements?

Comment: I don't know if this can help you, but some time ago I wrote an answer about improving Neo4j performance on large datasets with huge relationships. Hope it helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45770769/import-billions-of-nodes-and-relationships-to-neo4j-using-batch-import-on-window/45773618#45773618

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried some things which improved performance considerably.

Some neo4j performance guidelines that applies to my scenario:

1. **Process in batch:** Avoid doing cypher call (through bolt api call) for each csv row. Iterate through several fixed number of rows of csv, form list of maps where each map will be row of csv. Then pass this list of maps to cypher as  parameter. `UNWIND` this list inside cypher and perform the desired action. Repeat the same for next set of csv rows.
2. **Dont return node relationship objects from cypher** to java side. Instead try returning list of maps required as a final output. When we return list of nodes / relationships, we may have to reiterate through them to merge the properties with csv columns to form final output row (or map)
3. **Pass the csv column values to cypher:** To achieve point 2, send the csv column values (to be merged with graph properties) to cypher. Perform matching in cypher and form the output map by merging matched node's properties and input csv columns.
4. **Index node / relationship properties which are to be matched** ([Official docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/))
5. **Parameterized the cypher** ([API Example](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/org/neo4j/driver/v1/StatementRunner.html#run-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-), [Official docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/))

I did a quick dirty experiment as I explained below.

My input csv looked like this.

**inputDataCsv.csv**

```
csv-id1,csv-id2,csv-id3,outcol1,outcol2,outcol3
gppe0,ppe1,pe2,outcol1-val-0,outcol2-val-1,outcol3-val-2
gppe3,ppe4,pe5,outcol1-val-3,outcol2-val-4,outcol3-val-5
gppe6,ppe7,pe8,outcol1-val-6,outcol2-val-7,outcol3-val-8
...
```

To created the graph, I first created csvs of the form:

**gppe.csv (entities)**

```
gppe0,gppe_out_prop_1_val_0,gppe_out_prop_2_val_0,gppe_prop_X_val_0
gppe3,gppe_out_prop_1_val_3,gppe_out_prop_2_val_3,gppe_prop_X_val_3
gppe6,gppe_out_prop_1_val_6,gppe_out_prop_2_val_6,gppe_prop_X_val_6
...
```

**ppe.csv (entities)**

```
ppe1,ppe_out_prop_1_val_1,ppe_out_prop_2_val_1,ppe_prop_X_val_1
ppe4,ppe_out_prop_1_val_4,ppe_out_prop_2_val_4,ppe_prop_X_val_4
ppe7,ppe_out_prop_1_val_7,ppe_out_prop_2_val_7,ppe_prop_X_val_7
...
```

**pe.csv (entities)**

```
pe2,pe_out_prop_1_val_2,pe_out_prop_2_val_2,pe_prop_X_val_2
pe5,pe_out_prop_1_val_5,pe_out_prop_2_val_5,pe_prop_X_val_5
pe8,pe_out_prop_1_val_8,pe_out_prop_2_val_8,pe_prop_X_val_8
...
```

**gppeHasPpe.csv (relationships)**

```
gppe0,ppe1
gppe3,ppe4
gppe6,ppe7
...
```

**ppeContainsPe.csv (relationships)**

```
ppe1,pe2
ppe4,pe5
ppe7,pe8
...
```

I loaded this in neo4j as follows:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT  
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///gppe.csv' AS line    
CREATE (:GPPocEntity {id:line[0],gppe_out_prop_1: line[1], gppe_out_prop_2: line[2],gppe_out_prop_X: line[3]})   

USING PERIODIC COMMIT    
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///ppe.csv' AS line    
CREATE (:PPocEntity {id:line[0],ppe_out_prop_1: line[1], ppe_out_prop_2: line[2],ppe_out_prop_X: line[3]})

USING PERIODIC COMMIT    
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///pe.csv' AS line    
CREATE (:PocEntity {id:line[0],pe_out_prop_1: line[1], pe_out_prop_2: line[2],pe_out_prop_X: line[3]})

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///gppeHasPpe.csv' AS line
MATCH(gppe:GPPocEntity {id:line[0]})
MATCH(ppe:PPocEntity {id:line[1]})
MERGE (gppe)-[:has]->(ppe)

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///ppeContainsPe.csv' AS line
MATCH(ppe:PPocEntity {id:line[0]})
MATCH(pe:PocEntity {id:line[1]})
MERGE (ppe)-[:contains]->(pe)
```

Next I created indixes on lookup properties:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :GPPocEntity(id)

CREATE INDEX ON :PPocEntity(id)

CREATE INDEX ON :PocEntity(id)
```

Below is utility class which reads csv into list of maps:

```
package csv2csv;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.w3c.dom.stylesheets.LinkStyle;

public class Config {

    String configFilePath;
    Map csvColumnToGraphNodeMapping;
    List<Map> mappingsGraphRelations;
    Map<String,Map<String,String>> mappingsGraphRelationsMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String,String>>(); 
    List<String> outputColumnsFromCsv;
    Map outputColumnsFromGraph;

    public Config(String pConfigFilePath) {
        configFilePath = pConfigFilePath;

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {

            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(configFilePath));

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

            csvColumnToGraphNodeMapping = (HashMap) ((HashMap) jsonObject.get("csvColumn-graphNodeProperty-mapping"))
                    .get("mappings");
            mappingsGraphRelations = (ArrayList) ((HashMap) jsonObject.get("csvColumn-graphNodeProperty-mapping"))
                    .get("mappings-graph-relations");
            for(Map m : mappingsGraphRelations)
            {
                mappingsGraphRelationsMap.put(""+ m.get("start-entity") + "-" + m.get("end-entity"), m);
            }
            outputColumnsFromCsv = (ArrayList) ((HashMap) jsonObject.get("output-csv-columns"))
                    .get("columns-from-input-csv");
            outputColumnsFromGraph = (HashMap) ((HashMap) jsonObject.get("output-csv-columns"))
                    .get("columns-from-graph");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Below class performs merging and creates another csv:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.neo4j.driver.internal.value.MapValue;
import org.neo4j.driver.internal.value.NodeValue;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.AuthTokens;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Driver;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.GraphDatabase;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Record;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Session;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.StatementResult;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.StopWatch;

public class Csv2CsvUtil2 {
    static String inCsvFilePath = "D:\\Mahesh\\work\\files\\inputDataCsv.csv";
    static String outCsvFilePath = "D:\\Mahesh\\work\\files\\csvout.csv";

    private final static Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver(
              "bolt://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.basic("neo4j", "password"));   

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        mergeNonBatch();    
    }

    private static void merge() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {       
        List<Map<String,String>> csvRowMapList = new CsvReader(inCsvFilePath).getMapListFromCsv();
        Session session = driver.session();
        String cypherFilter = "";
        String cypher;
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File(outCsvFilePath));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        List<Map<String, String>> inputMapList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
        Map<String,Object> inputMapListMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
        cypher = "WITH {inputMapList} AS inputMapList"
                + " UNWIND inputMapList AS rowMap"
                + " WITH rowMap"
                + " MATCH (gppe:GPPocEntity {id:rowMap.csvid1})-[:has]->(ppe:PPocEntity {id:rowMap.csvid2})-[:contains]->(pe:PocEntity {id:rowMap.csvid3})"
                + " RETURN {id1:gppe.id,id2:ppe.id,id3:pe.id"
                +           ",gppeprop1: gppe.gppe_out_prop_1,gppeprop2: gppe.gppe_out_prop_2"
                +           ",ppeprop1: ppe.ppe_out_prop_1,ppeprop2: ppe.ppe_out_prop_2"
                +           ",peprop1: pe.pe_out_prop_1,peprop2: pe.pe_out_prop_2"
                +           ",outcol1:rowMap.outcol1,outcol2:rowMap.outcol2,outcol3:rowMap.outcol3}";

        int i;
        for(i=0;i<csvRowMapList.size();i++)
        {
            Map<String, String> rowMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            rowMap.put("csvid1", csvRowMapList.get(i).get("csv-id1"));
            rowMap.put("csvid2", csvRowMapList.get(i).get("csv-id2"));
            rowMap.put("csvid3", csvRowMapList.get(i).get("csv-id3"));
            rowMap.put("outcol1", csvRowMapList.get(i).get("outcol1"));
            rowMap.put("outcol2", csvRowMapList.get(i).get("outcol2"));
            rowMap.put("outcol3", csvRowMapList.get(i).get("outcol3"));
            inputMapList.add(rowMap);

            if(i%10000 == 0)  //run in batch
            {
                inputMapListMap.put("inputMapList", inputMapList);
                StatementResult stmtRes = session.run(cypher,inputMapListMap);
                List<Record> retList = stmtRes.list();
                for (Record record2 : retList) {
                    MapValue retMap = (MapValue) record2.get(0);
                    sb.append(retMap.get("id1")
                            +","+retMap.get("id2")
                            +","+retMap.get("id3")
                            +","+retMap.get("gppeprop1")
                            +","+retMap.get("gppeprop2")
                            +","+retMap.get("ppeprop1")
                            +","+retMap.get("ppeprop2")
                            +","+retMap.get("peprop1")
                            +","+retMap.get("peprop2")
                            +","+retMap.get("outcol1")
                            +","+retMap.get("outcol2")
                            +","+retMap.get("outcol3")
                            +"\n"
                            );  
                }
                inputMapList.clear();
            }
        }

        if(inputMapList.size() != 0)  //ingest remaining rows which does not complete 
                                      //10000 reords failing to form next batch 
        {
            inputMapListMap.put("inputMapList", inputMapList);
            StatementResult stmtRes = session.run(cypher,inputMapListMap);
            List<Record> retList = stmtRes.list();

            for (Record record2 : retList) {
                MapValue retMap = (MapValue) record2.get(0);
                sb.append(retMap.get("id1")
                        +","+retMap.get("id2")
                        +","+retMap.get("id3")
                        +","+retMap.get("gppeprop1")
                        +","+retMap.get("gppeprop2")
                        +","+retMap.get("ppeprop1")
                        +","+retMap.get("ppeprop2")
                        +","+retMap.get("peprop1")
                        +","+retMap.get("peprop2")
                        +","+retMap.get("outcol1")
                        +","+retMap.get("outcol2")
                        +","+retMap.get("outcol3")
                        +"\n"
                        );  
            }
        }
        pw.write(sb.toString());
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

Running in non batch mode was slowing stuff 10 times. When guidelines 2 to 4 werent followed, it was a lot slower. Will love someone if all above things are correct, if I made any mistake, if I am missing anything, if stuff can be further improved.